# Can I run website made with ASP.NET 4(.x) with mod_mono on Apache server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, mono

*Can I run a website programmed with asp.net 4.x with mod_mono on an Apache web server*?

I know this question has been asked many times and I've read quite a lot of them, but still I'm perplexed. Many answers seem to to be **yes, you can run it**, based on the Compatibility page on the Mono project site. But on the mod_mono project page it says:

> Mono has an implementation of ASP.NET 2.0, ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET AJAX.

This would seem to imply that I **can't run** ASP.NET 4.x web site with mod_mono. Therefore, I'm quite confused! Is the mod_mono page out-of-date, or is the question understood as a question about running .exe-applications made with .net on a linux system? I need to run .aspx web pages coded with asp.net 4.x (wrote in vb), and for that end I would like to know is it possible or do I need a IIS server for that?

Comment: I myself have ran ASP.NET 4.X applications in a mod_mono enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you may need to copy some dll's to bin folder. I had to copy

```
System.Web.Helpers.dll
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
```

Some other dll's you should not copy. For example System.Configuration.dll does not work for me, so I had to delete it from the bin folder, so Mono's version is used.